# Showing proper divergence of the sequence $x_n=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ from definition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

I have to show that the sequence $x_n = \displaystyle\frac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ is properly divergent from the definiton of proper divergence. This is the following definition I must use.

> " For any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, there exits $K(\alpha)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n\geq K(\alpha)$ then $x_n> \alpha$. This implies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n = \infty$

Some help would really be appeciated!

Answer (score 1):

For any $\alpha$, for any $n>(|\alpha|+1)^{2}$, then 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}&=\dfrac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\\
&=\sqrt{n+1}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\\
&>\sqrt{n+1}-1\\
&>\sqrt{(|\alpha|+1)^{2}}-1\\
&=|\alpha|+1-1\\
&=|\alpha|\\
&\geq\alpha.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$n \ge 1$;

$a_n:=\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n+1}}> \dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n+n}}=$

$(1/√2)√n.$

Let $M >0$ be given.

Need to show that there is a $n_0$ s.t. for $n\ge n_0$

$a_n>M$ .

Archimedean principle:

There is a $n_0   >2 M^2$;

For $n\ge n_0:$

$a_n >(1/√2)√n >$

$(1/√2)√n_0 >M.$